# how to change style of html element based on content of div

Tags: html, css, angular, ej2-syncfusion

[image]I have

```
<div class="e-tab-text"
  _ngcontent-ori-c237=""
  role="presentation">2 Assign Roles</div>
```

I want to add custom style so for the number value "2" to show in a circle, in blue color, and "assign role" in black color using Angular, this is coming from ej2 angular syncfusion tab

I'm trying to expect html style changes based on content of text:

```
<e-tabitem [header]='headerText[1]'>

    <ng-template #content>
        <div id='rules'>
           <p>Assign rules</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</e-tabitem>
```

Comment: I'm not clear about your question.

Comment: Do you build element with such text by iterating over some array of data, or is it hard-coded in the template? Is it the only element that needs such styling or are there more? Are you receiving the text from some service?